# jQuery .append() Overwrite Previous .append()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I Just Ran Into A Problem Related To jQuery,And Javascript.
Here Is My (Piece Of) HTML Code:

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" class="input" id="display-name" placeholder="Display Name">
    <input type="text" class="input" id="username" placeholder="Username">
    <textarea class=" textarea" id="post" placeholder="Write The Posts..."></textarea>
    <br>
    <button type="button" class="button is-info" id="publish-post">Send</button>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container post-result">
    <p class="subtitle" id="post-status" style="color: darkgray;">No Posts Yet.</p>
</div>
```

And This Is My Entire JavaScript Code:

```
$(() => {
    let postCount = 0;
    $("#publish-post").click(() => {
        const displayName = $("#display-name").val();
        const username = $("#username").val().toLowerCase().replaceAll(' ','_');
        const post = $("#post").val();
        const CurrentTime = new Date()
            .toString()
            .split(' ');
        if (username != undefined || post != undefined) {
            let index = "#post-status";
            postCount++;
            console.log(username,post);
            $(index).text(`${postCount.toString()} Posts.`);
            $(index).append(`
            <div class="card post-${postCount}">
                <div class="card-content">
                    <div class="media-content">
                        <p class="subtitle is-4" style="color: darkgray;">Post #${postCount}
                        <p class="title is-4">${displayName}</p>
                        <p class="subtitle is-5" style="color: darkgray;">aciduser/${username}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <p>${post}<p>
                    </div>
                </div
            </div>
            `);
        }
    });
});
```

Lets Say I Input The Display Name "Foo", Username "Bar" And Post "Foo Bar Baz", Then I Click Send.
Yes Its Working But When I Input Again It Instead Overwriting The Foo Bar Baz And Replace It With The New Value (Even Without New Value, Just Random Clicking), I Want It To Add New Element (Eg. When I Post "Foo Bar Baz",It Add Element Foo Bar Baz And When I Post "Bar Foo Baz" it adds new element on top of Foo Bar Baz). How Do I Can Fix This? Big Thanks To People Who Answered :)

Comment: I *think* (after getting a headache from Those Random Caps) what you mean is that when you add a new "post", the old "posts" are being removed and you want to keep the old posts. If so, change `$(index).text(`${postCount.toString()} Posts.`);` to `.append(` as `.text` is clearing out your `$(index)` first.

Comment: I know this has nothing todo with your issue, but should't **if (username != undefined || post != undefined)** be **if (username != undefined && post != undefined)**. Just saying that this might distract from your issue

Comment: @freedomn-m Yeah my random-caps habits is annoying, its even annoy myself. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The:

```
$(index).text(`${postCount.toString()} Posts.`);
```

is replacing the content each time you post, and then you are appending after that.  If you move the postCount.toString() Posts. to the append then you'll have a running log instead of overwriting the prior result.  Added some labels.

```js
$(() => {
    let postCount = 0;
    $("#publish-post").click(() => {
        const displayName = $("#display-name").val();
        const username = $("#username").val().toLowerCase().replaceAll(' ','_');
        const post = $("#post").val();
        const CurrentTime = new Date()
            .toString()
            .split(' ');
        if (username != undefined || post != undefined) {
            let index = "#post-status";
            postCount++;
            console.log(username,post);
            $(index).prepend(`${postCount.toString()} Posts.
            <div class="card post-${postCount}">
                <div class="card-content">
                    <div class="media-content">
                        <p class="subtitle is-4" style="color: darkgray;">Post #${postCount}
                        <p class="title is-4">Display Name:  ${displayName}</p>
                        <p class="subtitle is-5" style="color: darkgray;">User Path:  aciduser/${username}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        Content:
                        <p>${post}<p>
                    </div>
                </div
            </div>
            `);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" class="input" id="display-name" placeholder="Display Name">
    <input type="text" class="input" id="username" placeholder="Username">
    <textarea class=" textarea" id="post" placeholder="Write The Posts..."></textarea>
    <br>
    <button type="button" class="button is-info" id="publish-post">Send</button>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container post-result">
    Post History:
    <p class="subtitle" id="post-status" style="color: darkgray;"></p>
</div>
```

Are you looking for something like that ?

Comment: Your answer should include some explanation of your changes. Don't expect everyone to do a line-by-line comparison.

Comment: @SScotti Yes thank You but How do I get the latest post on top instead on bottom?

Comment: I just edited and changed append to prepend, reverses the order.

Answer (score 0):

append output in parent div.

```js
$(index).text(`${postCount.toString()} Posts.`);
$(index).parent().append(`
```

click **[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ap09hxLy/8/)** to see or **run snippest**

```js
$(() => {
    let postCount = 0;
    $("#publish-post").click(() => {
        const displayName = $("#display-name").val();
        const username = $("#username").val().toLowerCase().replaceAll(' ','_');
        const post = $("#post").val();
        const CurrentTime = new Date()
            .toString()
            .split(' ');
        if (username != undefined || post != undefined) {
            let index = "#post-status";
            postCount++;
            console.log(username,post);
            $(index).text(`${postCount.toString()} Posts.`);
            $(index).parent().append(`
            <div class="card post-${postCount}">
                <div class="card-content">
                    <div class="media-content">
                        <p class="subtitle is-4" style="color: darkgray;">Post #${postCount}
                        <p class="title is-4">${displayName}</p>
                        <p class="subtitle is-5" style="color: darkgray;">aciduser/${username}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <p>${post}<p>
                    </div>
                </div
            </div>
            `);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" class="input" id="display-name" placeholder="Display Name">
    <input type="text" class="input" id="username" placeholder="Username">
    <textarea class=" textarea" id="post" placeholder="Write The Posts..."></textarea>
    <br>
    <button type="button" class="button is-info" id="publish-post">Send</button>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="post-result" style="color: darkgray;" class="container post-result">
    <p class="subtitle" id="post-status" style="color: black;">No Posts Yet.</p>
</div>
```